# Understanding tostring() method ?

Tags: java

What is the use of toString() Method ? 
i have a sub class and i need to use a tostring() method in it. How can i use it to print "C10". If i am trying to make chutes and ladder game. This is the Error message that i am getting

Chute.java:12: error: incompatible types
     return System.out.print("C10") ;
                            ^
  required: String
  found:    void
1 error

code :

```
public String toString() 
{
 return System.out.print("C10") ;

}
```

}

Comment: Your method says return `String`...

Comment: You should never do printing inside of a method - instead, return the string that you would otherwise print, and then you can use it for other things besides printing.

Comment: @Patashu:  Never say "never".  There are times when printing while in the method is useful for (entry level) debugging.

Comment: @Makota Yeah, sorry, I meant more like 'don't print things that you can return instead'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`System.out.print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) is a void method.  It doesn't return anything, despite the fact that it prints to your screen.

If you want to return something from your `toString()` method, you only need to return what you wanted from the `System.out.print` method.

```
public String toString() {
    return "C10";
}
```

Comment: i tried it wihtout using system.out.print and it works perfectly fine. thank you soo much

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind `toString` is producing a `String` representation of your object. Printing it or using it in any other way is entirely up to you.

```
class Snake {
    public String toString() {
        return "C10";
    }
}

public static void main() {
    Snake mySnake = new Snake();
    // This prints "C10"
    System.out.println(mySnake);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `toString()` method should return a string representation of your class:

```
public String toString()
{
   return "C10";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are getting that error because you aren't returning anything at all. `System.out.print()` is a method that, as a side effect, prints the string provided to standard out.

To return the String, you need to do this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "C10";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, a function should return the defined type in signature

public String method return a String, so you should return the value "C10"

```
public String toString() {
    return "C10";
}
```

You can add the print function, optionaly before the return:

```
public String toString() {
    String value = "C10"; //user var to not copy the value;
    System.out.print(value);
    return value;
}
```